# What if update.php fails due to code errors?

Tags: entities, database

I sometimes run into the issue, when my PHP code has errors. I run update.php, but it fails with a php error message. After that, Drupal seems to think that the database is up-to-date, but it isn't. Trouble is, running update.php again does not solve the problem.

For example, just now, it has failed to create the tables for a newly created entity. update.php does nothing, but all my Entity code – of course – fails with database errors.

I don't know how to recover from this situation, other than uninstalling and reinstalling the module, which means killing all content first.

Comment: Restore the database from the backup you've made before running update.php and then fix the module code. If it's not your own module look in the issue queue.

Comment: Backup?? Er ... :-D

Comment: OK, I didn't have a backup, so what I did was: 1) bugfixes, 2) export all configuration, 3) uninstall and reinstall module, 4) import configuration. I didn't mind the content, but needed to keep configuration (fields etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You could also rerun the update after you fixed your code.

See here:
[reseting the hook_update_n status of a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42204/reseting-the-hook-update-n-status-of-a-module#42207)

Comment: Yes, if you've located the error and know that it stopped the update hook early, before it could make changes to the entity tables, then you can re-run it on the same database. Otherwise you don't know if the database is corrupted and it is advisable to restore the database first.